# Is it possible to obtain the Class object of a primitive type in Java when all you know is it's name?

Tags: java

For the primitive types: int, double, short, etc...

Given:

```
String typeName = "double";
```

How do I get `double.class`?

For a regular class we can do the following:

```
String typeName = "java.lang.Integer"
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(typeName);  
// Class.forName(typeName) returns Double.class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Check out the [reflection documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html). Go to the "Class.forName()" section and there, you can find a note:

> This cannot be used for primitive types.

One option might be to create a method that will recognize the primitive types and return the matching class (i.e. Integer.class, Double.class, etc...)

Comment: Just a small amendment: There _are_ `.class`s for the primitive types: `int.class`, `double.class`, etc. You don't have to use the boxed Object types' classes.

Comment: Also, double.class and Double.class are completely different classes (Same goes for the other primitives).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying something clever, since there are only 8 primitives would it be so bad to write a switch/case statement, or hard code them in some other way such as a Map (suggested by Scorpion in comment below) ?

The [Spring Framework](http://git.springsource.org/spring-mobile/spring-android/blobs/063e6216bd746786532515cdc2f7f1d670e98fd0/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java#line121) takes this approach for its version of Class.forName.

Comment: Or a map of string to the corresponding class

Comment: Don't forget `void` as 9th primitive class.

Answer (score 1):

If you click on @mprivat's link and read the section on "The .class Syntax," what you get at the very beginning is:

> If the type is available but there is no instance then it is possible
>   to obtain a Class by appending ".class" to the name of the type. This
>   is also the easiest way to obtain the Class for a primitive type.

So `double.class` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code to find the class of a primitive type when all you know is it's name.

```
public class CheckPrimitve {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample s = new Sample();
        try {
            System.out.println(s.getClass().getField("sampleDouble").getType() == double.class); // returns true
            System.out.println(s.getClass().getField("sampleDouble").getType().isPrimitive()); // returns true
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {          
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
}

class Sample {
    public double sampleDouble;
    public Sample() {
        sampleDouble = 10d;
    }
}
```

Comment: `getPrimitiveClass` is not `public` so you can't use it.

Comment: It's OK, but it doesn't `find the class of a primitive type when all you know is it's name`

Comment: s.getClass().getField("sampleDouble").getType() returns double.class - I suppose this is what means returning class of a primitive type who's field name is 'sampleDouble'. In any other case where you just want the class of a primitive type and not specific to it's related field, Dennis Meng replies seems a perfect solution.

Comment: The `name` should be one of the primitive types(e.g. 'double', 'int'..) the question is how to get `Class` object of this `name`. auser's answer says that you can't do it in a common way(`Class.forName()`) and codebox's answer gives a nice workaround.